# Convert firebase.firestore.timestamp to date before patchValue of data in a reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load a field which is stored as a timestamp in firestore and populate a “mat-datepicker“ form control which uses Date formats.

Is there any way of modifying the format of the "dob" data before it reaches the Angular Material datepicker control?  The date picker doesn't like the timestamp format and refuses to display it for obvious reasons.

Below is my attempt at shortening the existing code minus any transform attempt because I am stuck! It may not even work! The full code does though.

Basically use the path string passed in to create an instance of a Firestore Document then patch values into the myForm controls.

I know firebase.firestore.Timestamp has a toDate() option but I am an Angular noob and need a few pointers on how to transform timestamp to date before the value is stored in the control?

```
// Firestore Document
private fireDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument;
@Input() path: string;
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private afs: AngularFirestore) { }   

ngOnInit() {

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      middleName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      dob: new FormControl(),
    });

  this.loadDoc();
}

loadDoc() {

this.fireDoc = this.afs.doc(this.path);
    this.fireDoc
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        tap(doc => {
          if (doc) {
            this.myForm.patchValue(doc);
          }
        }),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on angularfirebase.slack.com and was given this resolution.

```
      pipe(
        map(({dob, ...data}) => {
        return {
          ...data,
          dob: dob.toDate(),
        };
      }),
```

tap(...

in my scenario I had 5 timestamps in the firestore and was hitting brick walls. The code above worked for me.